# Filter Get-ChildItem by an array

Tags: powershell

I have just started using PowerShell today, and I have an intention list files by a few patterns in an array, for instance:

```
$matchPattern = (
                  "SomeCompany.SaaS.Core.Mvc*",
                  "SomeCompany.SaaS.Core.UI.Framework*"
                );
```

I want to list files in a `$sourceDir` where any of the item in the above array matches.

I can do this, and it works:

```
foreach ($item in $matchPattern)
{
    Get-ChildItem $sourceDir | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $item}
}
```

Just for learning purposes, can I do it in pipe-lining?

**Something similar to this:**

```
Get-ChildItem $sourceDir | Where-Object { $matchPattern -contains $_.Name  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just do:

```
gci "$someDir\*" -include $matchPattern
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. Can please kindly explain `\*` and how -include works with arrays.

Comment: @Munim - technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347686.aspx. `-include` expects a string array of wildcard patterns to include and it is applicable only when the path itself points to contents of a directory (`\*`) or you use `-recurse`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

Assuming an array $a exists with some strings in it:

```
gci $someDir | %{$a -eq $_.name}
```

Whenever the name of the directory found by gci matches a value in the $a array, it will echo out that value. So if $someDir=C:\ and "windows" was an element in $a, the output would be just "windows" if it was the only match.

Edit: My mistake, I did not realize you wanted the * as a wildcard and not a literal, this only matches literals. Solved below.

For pattern matches, you can use regex arrays. Define one like so

```
[regex]$patt = “^(Win.*|.*Files)$”
```

You can now compare all matches like the above

```
gci $someDir | ?{$_.name -match $patt}
```

Comment: Didn't work, I tried to put `-like` instead of `-eq`, but not luck. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks, but I need the list to be in an array. I populate the list from a text file which is maintained by some other guys. `Regex` with `OR` is probably not appreciated here.